# React changing values without actually changing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a game like purple pairs of the purple palace game. What I am trying to do is that whenever two elements are clicked which are not equal in value, then the cards should automatically close but what is happening is something different. Whenever I clicked two wrong cards, then chose a different card then the value is getting changed even though I have not written any code to do so. This is very frustrating, I am getting nowhere trying to solve this. Please help me solve this.

**Original Code Pen link** [Click here to visit](https://codepen.io/sauravk7077/pen/pobOdqx)

I think the problem lies somewhere in `handleClick` function.

[image]

```js
function Card(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(props.chosen);
  handleClick = (e) => {
    if (props.chosen) {
      setShow(true);
    } else {
      props.onClick();
      setShow(!show);
    }
  };
  const style1 = {
    background: "grey",
    transform: `rotateY(${!show ? 0 : 180}deg)`
  };
  const style2 = {
    background: "#aaa",
    transform: `rotateY(${show ? 0 : 180}deg)`
  };
  return (
    <div class="container" onClick={handleClick}>
      <div className="flip" style={style1}></div>
      <div className="flip" style={style2}>
        {props.value}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class GameBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      score: 0,
      time: 0,
      list: [...generateObList(), ...generateObList()],
      count: 0
    };
  }

  handleClick = async (id) => {
    await this.clickBtn(id);
    const list = _.cloneDeep(this.state.list);
    const current = list.find((a) => a.id === id);
    for (let x of list) {
      if (
        x.clicked &&
        x.id != id &&
        x.value == list.find((a) => a.id == id).value
      ) {
        x.chosen = true;
        x.clicked = false;
        current.chosen = true;
        current.clicked = false;
        this.setState((prev) => ({
          list: prev.list.map((el) =>
            el.id === id ? current : el.value === current.value ? x : el
          ),
          score: prev.score + 1
        }));
      } else if (this.state.count % 2 == 0 && x.clicked) {
        console.log("Entered");
        current.clicked = false;
        x.clicked = false;
        this.setState((prev) => ({
          list: prev.list.map((el) =>
            el.id === id ? current : el.value === current.value ? x : el
          )
        }));
      }
    }
  };

  clickBtn = (id) => {
    const current = _.cloneDeep(this.state.list).find((e) => e.id === id);
    let deClick = current.clicked;
    current.clicked = !current.clicked;
    this.setState((prev) => ({
      list: prev.list.map((el) => (el.id === id ? current : el)),
      count: prev.count + (deClick ? -1 : 1)
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const boardStyle = {
      gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(5, 1fr)`,
      gridTemplateRows: `repeat(5,1r)`
    };
    let list = this.state.list.map((n) => (
      <Card
        value={n.value}
        onClick={(e) => {
          this.handleClick(n.id);
        }}
        chosen={n.chosen}
        clicked={n.clicked}
      />
    ));
    return (
      <div class="gameBoard" style={boardStyle}>
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your `generateObList` function?

Comment: It generates object with properties such as `id, value, chosen, clicked`

Comment: Did you try adding a key props to items inside your list ? This might help

Comment: Okay, I'll try.

Comment: @Axnyff, It seems to cause more problems. It is now adding more elements than there should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some serious issues in the handleClick function. The main thing that went wrong was that you were somehow managing to replace list items with other list items.

The overwrite issue is happening in this line. I'm not entirely sure why this is causing the issue, but it is.

```
          list: prev.list.map((el) =>
            el.id === id ? current : el.value === current.value ? x : el
          )
```

If you just replace it with the following, then the issue dissapears:

```
          list: prev.list.map((el) => el.clicked ? {...el, clicked:false}: el)
```

The clickBtn wasn't an async function, so using await on it wouldn't do anything. If you want to await for the state to change, you need to resolve a promise. I haven't worked with class components in a while, so I don't know if this would be a particularly encouraged way of working with them, but there are likely other ways:

```
      await new Promise((resolve) =>
        this.setState(
          (prev) => ({
            list: prev.list.map((card) =>
              card.clicked ? { ...card, clicked: false } : card
            ),
            freeze: false
          }),
          () => resolve()
        )
      );
```

Another thing to note is that you were keeping the state of which cards were clicked in the GameBoard, so there was no reason to have Card be stateful, in fact, that's the reason why cards wouldn't flip back over.

By changing the start of cards from using `useState` to just the props values, that's fixed:

```
  const show = props.chosen||props.clicked;
  handleClick = (e) => {
    if (props.chosen) {
    } else {
      props.onClick();
    }
  };
```

https://codepen.io/ZachHaber/pen/yLJGayv

---

## Refactors:

I did some refactoring to get everything working while I was figuring out what went wrong.

I also had some fun implementing logic, which is why I added the flipping behavior with a timeout when the user guesses wrong.

```js
const {shuffle} = _;

const numbersList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let id = 0;
const generateObList = () => {
  return numbersList.map((e) => ({
    // Use something more guaranteed to not be the same value
    // Math.random *could* clash, but is very unlikely to.
    id: id++,
    value: e,
    chosen: false,
    clicked: false
  }));
};
// Using a shuffle algorithm here to shuffle the tiles.
const generateList = () => shuffle([...generateObList(), ...generateObList()]);

function Card(props) {
  const show = props.chosen || props.clicked;
  // Remove the local state here, it's just problematic
  // Let the parent control the state.
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (props.chosen) {
    } else {
      props.onClick();
    }
  };
  const style1 = {
    background: "grey",
    transform: `rotateY(${!show ? 0 : 180}deg)`
  };
  const style2 = {
    background: "#aaa",
    transform: `rotateY(${show ? 0 : 180}deg)`
  };
  return (
    <div className="container" onClick={handleClick}>
      <div className="flip" style={style1}></div>
      <div className="flip" style={style2}>
        {props.value}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class GameBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      score: 0,
      time: 0,

      list: generateList(),
      count: 0,
      freeze: false
    };
  }
  timerId = null;
  performUpdate = (id) => {
    // Flip the relevant card in the list
    const list = this.state.list.map((card) =>
      card.id === id ? { ...card, clicked: !card.clicked } : card
    );
    // Get the active card
    const current = list.find((card) => card.id === id);
    // Get all cards that match the current value
    let matches = list.filter((card) => card.value === current.value);
    // Somehow the card was already chosen
    // Likely can remove this because this condition is also in the children
    if (matches.every((card) => card.chosen)) {
      return; // invalid click, don't do anything
    }
    // the matches are all clicked, now they are valid to be chosen!
    if (matches.every((card) => card.clicked)) {
      this.setState((prev) => ({
        list: list.map((card) =>
          card.value !== current.value
            ? card
            : { ...card, clicked: false, chosen: true }
        ),
        score: prev.score + 1,
        count: prev.count + 1
      }));
      return;
    }
    // There are 2 cards clicked, reset them after a timer!
    if (list.filter((card) => card.clicked).length === 2) {
      // Have to post the current click state change -
      // Make it so it will flip over the tile briefly
      this.setState((prev) => ({ list, count: prev.count + 1, freeze: true }));
      // Then after a timeout, flip it back over
      this.timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState((prev) => ({
          list: prev.list.map((card) =>
            card.clicked ? { ...card, clicked: false } : card
          ),
          freeze: false
        }));
      }, 500);
      return;
    }
    // At this point it's just a normal click:
    // set the new adjusted list, and increment count.
    this.setState((prev) => ({
      list,
      count: prev.count + 1
    }));
  };
  handleClick = (id) => {
    // Waiting for board to flip tiles over currently. User is impatient
    // Could just return in this case if you want users to wait
    if (this.state.freeze) {
      clearTimeout(this.timerId);
      // Perform the update to clear the clicked status and freeze status
      // and wait for it to resolve before continuing
      this.setState(
        (prev) => ({
          list: prev.list.map((card) =>
            card.clicked ? { ...card, clicked: false } : card
          ),
          freeze: false
        }),
        () => this.performUpdate(id)
      );
    } else {
      this.performUpdate(id);
    }
  };
  reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: 0,
      score: 0,
      time: 0,
      freeze: false,
      list: generateList()
    });
  };
  render() {
    const boardStyle = {
      gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(5, 1fr)`,
      gridTemplateRows: `repeat(5,1r)`
    };
    let list = this.state.list.map((card) => (
      <Card
        key={card.id}
        value={card.value}
        onClick={(e) => {
          this.handleClick(card.id);
        }}
        chosen={card.chosen}
        clicked={card.clicked}
      />
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="gameBoard" style={boardStyle}>
          {list}
        </div>
        <div>
          move count: {this.state.count}
          <br />
          score: {this.state.score}
        </div>
        {this.state.score === this.state.list.length / 2 && (
          <button onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<GameBoard/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.gameBoard {
  display: grid;
}
.container .flip {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 4em;
  transition: transform 400ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.39, 0.3, 0.95);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: You have done some extra though, it was not need. Thanks for the help anyway.